# About middle-stage processing using Mongo's FIND

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using FIND with a cursor in MongoDB, can I interrupt before the cursor reaches the end?

Thank you.
Tatsuya

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question?

Comment: Hi Amaranadh Meda,

Thank you for your reply.
FIND using a cursor uses MongooseLibrary.Please tell me how to handle interruption when using Mongoose.
Before processing all items extracted by cursor, if the conditions are met, I want to interrupt the process and return resolve.

Best regards,
Tatsuya

Comment: -　Simplified program content
return new Promise(
function(resolve, reject) {
let count = 0;
that.find({ })
.cursor()
.on('data', function(doc) {
count++;
console.log(doc);
})
.on('end', function() {
datas = {
"count": count
}
resolve(datas);
}
},
function(err, doc) {
if (err) { reject(err); }
resolve(doc)
});
});